# Cannot cross-compile for arm with c++17

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, arm, c++17, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile c++14/c++17 code for my raspberry pi. I am sure it worked on my old PC. However, when I try to compile it on my new pc, it returns me the following error.

```
    $ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ main.cpp -std=c++17
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++17’
```

I thought it is the compiler issue, the version of the compiler I am using is:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --version
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1+bzr2650 - Linaro GCC 2014.03) 4.8.3 20140303 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I try to get the newest compiler with

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-armel-cross libc6-dev-armel-cross binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi libncurses5-dev build-essential bison flex libssl-dev bc
```

Yet, the version is still the same, which can only compile c++11.

How can I update the arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ compiler?? I am pretty sure there is a compiler that works since I used it before, but not sure how I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easiest way to solve this issue is to directly install the newest cross-compiler

```
sudo apt-get install g++-9-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

and use the compiler as (just an example of using c++17)

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-9 main.cpp -std=c++17
```